# How to suppress virtual methods in PHP?

Tags: php, virtual-functions

Let's say I have class Animal and Dog (Dog inherits from Animal). For each class I have a method (protected) `foo` with identical signature. Those methods should be regular methods, non-virtual ones. But since PHP makes all non-private methods virtual now I have a problem.

Before I start writing some workarounds maybe it could be solved in simpler ways. Namely:

- is it possible in PHP to mark a method as non-virtual?
- "sitting" inside given class (Animal or Dog) is it possible to call `foo` in context of **current** class, so virtual mechanism will not kick in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark a method as [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php):

```
class foo {
    final protected function bar() {} //can not be overriden
}
```

Or even mark a class as final:

```
final class foo { // can not be extended
    //...
}
```

You can use the `self` keyword in conjunction with a method call to call a method in the context of the current class:

```
class A {
    function aa() { echo 1; }
    function cc() { self::aa(); }
    function dd() { $this->aa(); }
}

class B extends A {
    function aa() { echo 2; }
    function bb() { self::aa(); }
}

$b = new B;
$b->bb(); //2 - the value from B::aa() - call from B's context
$b->cc(); //1 - the value from A::aa() - call from A's context
$b->dd(); //2 - the value from B::aa() - regular virtual call
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first two answers you gave cannot be used -- as I wrote signatures are the same, and those classes use inheritance, but the third works as charm, so once again -- thank you!